# Select all except if specific cell value in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm stuck and I can't figure it out, so I would appreciate any help.

At this point i have table *journal* which consists of columns:

```
id | name | type(int) | classification | data      | journalUser | start_date(default NULL)
1  |  John  |  1      |  2             |  data123  |  1          |  10-11-2019
2  |  Peter |  2      |  2             |  data123  |  1          |  10-11-2019
3  |  Ash   |  2      |  2             |  data123  |  NULL       |  NULL
4  |  BUBU  |  2      |  2             |  data123  |  3          |  10-11-2019
```

I want to make query where I select all, but with exceptions, for example: SELECT * from journal, but if column type = 2, than select this row too if journalUser = 1 AND second check if column type = 2 and start_date IS NULL, than select this row too.

As the result, from table above, from query I wan to get result

```
id | name | type(int) | classification | data | journalUser | start_date(default NULL)
1  |  John  |  1  |  2  |  data123  |  1  |  10-11-2019
2  |  Peter |  2  |  2  |  data123  |  1  |  10-11-2019
3  |  Ash   |  2  |  2  |  data123  |  NULL  |  NULL
```

Comment: You say you want to select all rows with exceptions.  Then you give exceptions as rows you want to select.  I'm totally confused.  Can you describe the rows that you *don't* want.

Comment: Mainly I don't want to select rows which have, column type = 2 AND journalUser != 1

Comment: Why don't you get the 4th row then ? Type is 1

Comment: Sorry, misspelled. Now edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a specific case when the `type` is 2.

To get the rows with `type = 2` along with either (considering the expected output) `journalUser = 1` or `start_date = null`, this can be written this way :

```
type = 2 AND (journalUser = 1 OR start_date IS NULL)
```

To make sure you have others type too, you can add an `OR` condition such as :

```
OR type <> 2.
```

This will give this query :

```
SELECT *
FROM journal
WHERE (type = 2 AND (journalUser = 1 OR start_date IS NULL))
    OR type <> 2
```